# How to insert "get_template_part()" based on Category ID?

Tags: templates

I am trying to insert a part of my template into a Category Archive page.

How would I go about that?

I guess I'd need something like this:

```
   <?php
    $catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
        $catid = $cat->term_id;

        if ($catid == 10) {
          get_template_part('1','2') << ? 
        }
        if ($catid == 7) {
          get_template_part('3','4') << ?
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: - and would it need an ELSE statement at the end?

Comment: As written, your code is going to look for files named `1-2.php` (then `1.php`) and `3-4.php` (then `3.php`) in your theme. Also, to answer the `else` question: you'd need an `else` statement if you want to set a default template-part to load (ie if `$catid` is neither `7` nor `10`).

Comment: Thanks @PatJ - so basically there appears nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: Aside from the `<<?` text, which I assume were meant as pointers for us to look at and not actual parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is hooking to the filter `template_include` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/

You'll find some exmple at https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/